# How to lists all shortcuts available for currently active major mode?

Tags: key-bindings, helm

I simply want to get the list of shortcuts.

For example, when my cursor is in Treemacs, I press '?' and then mini-buffer opens which show all available shortcuts.
But same thing isn't true for other major modes like 'eww' etc.
I simply don't want to navigate to documentation everytime.

I use 'helm' if it helps!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Normally I use `C-h m` (`M-x describe-mode`) for this task.

The opened **Help** buffer lists currently used modes, and then short information on each of the modes, starting with the major one and usually providing a list of available key bindings.

Additionally, in some major modes, `?` and/or `C-h` output the most - expectedly - useful key bindings.

Also, there's a very useful `M-x describe-keymap` command, available since `Emacs 28.1` (current development snapshot 28.0.50). I often use it when I'd like to explore a particular keymap without going to the source (so *not only* the currently active major-mode's bindings). For example, `M-x describe-keymap <RET> dired-mode-map`.

P.S. You *might* also find it helpful to take a look at `C-h ?` for the list of the most useful **help bindings**.
`C-h m` is currently listed as the first one (in my setup).

Comment: `describe-keymap` is not available in vanilla emacs-27.2? At least, not in my vanilla 27.2.

Comment: @FranBurstall function `describe-keymap` was added on 24th of Aug 2019, so it should be available in [`Emacs` >= 26.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/history.html). See [help-fns.el blame](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blame/master/lisp/help-fns.el) with the changes to this function during the last 2 years.

Comment: I found 'helm-descbinds' helpful which was recommended in the link mentioned by Tyler in his comment.

Comment: @Y.E. `describe-keymap` was added 2 years ago to `help-fns.el` on the master branch but never made it to the 27 branch: check https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27/lisp/help-fns.el.

Comment: @FranBurstall yeah, that's a long journey for such a useful command. Anyway, 28.1 is going to be released soon, so not so long to wait for those who uses the latest stable release.

Comment: @FranBurstall, I clarified in the answer when `describe-keymap` was/is introduced. I could have spotted the exact release sooner, answering your first comment (just looking at its `C-h f` output), but followed a more complex route :-). Thanks for your feedback.